# Upload Excel xlsm file to php script using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, winhttp, winhttprequest

I would like to upload an Excel xlsm file to a php script from VBA. I found the following code:

```
Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

Dim strURL As String
Dim StrFileName As String
Dim FormFields As String
Dim path As String
Dim name As String

   StrFileName = "c:\temp\ctc1output.xls"
   strURL = "http://www.tri-simulation.com/P3/"


   WinHttpReq.Open "POST", strURL, False


   ' Set the header
  WinHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"


   FormFields = """fileulp=" & StrFileName & """"
   FormFields = FormFields + "&"
   FormFields = FormFields + """sfpath=P3"""

   WinHttpReq.Send FormFields


   ' Display the status code and response headers.
   MsgBox WinHttpReq.GetAllResponseHeaders
   MsgBox WinHttpReq.ResponseText
```

1. Should I handle the file as a binary file or another type of file?
2. Can I upload the file while it is still open (I want to upload the file from which the VBA is running from)?

I am not sure if I'm on the right track. 
I'm also not sure about what the headers and form fields should be.

Thx for any help.

Comment: HI, from your code, you are only sending the file name to server. You need to somehow convert the file into binaries and include them in your POST message.

Comment: Hi, I can see that the file has to be uploaded as a binary file. I'm using the code from [here](http://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/vb6-using-wininet-to-post-binary-file/). It also seems i dont need to make a copy. My problem now is that I need send some text with the post. Will that be a seperate request or can I include it somehow with the first one? Sorry if I seem redundant, but this is my first time with this topic.

Comment: you'll have to simulate a browser assembling a POST request and base64-encode your file, which can be done but is a bit tedious.  another option would be to run [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) which only needs the filename and the upload form parameters (the curl executable can be run from vba).

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to base64 encode anything. Follow the [sample code you have found](http://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/vb6-using-wininet-to-post-binary-file/) but before preparing the file (before *'---prepare body* comment) just add your other texts (form entries) like this

```
sPostData = sPostData & "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & vbCrLf & _
     "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""" & Name & """"
sPostData = sPostData & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
     pvToUtf8(Value) & vbCrLf
```

... where `Name` and `Value` are the designed name and the actual text that you want to include in service request. For the function `pvToUtf8` implementation take a look at [this Google Cloud Print service connector](https://github.com/wqweto/VbGcp/blob/master/Src/cGcpService.cls). The snippet above is taken from `pvRestAddParam` function of the same connector.